# Call a value to async Task in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have below code to set the values on the strings/ints that i passed over in parameters. I need to reach that `ID = value.id` in a call im doing in the ViewModel but it gives me null.

All code is in my ViewModel:

```
private int _id;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
    }

private TodoItem _todoItem;
    public TodoItem TodoItem
    {
        get => _todoItem;
        set
        {
            _todoItem = value;
            ID = value.id;
        }
    }
```

This is where I call the RestService and I include this id to get right call from api:

```
public async Task Get()
    {
        //_todoItem.id is null!!!!
        var PinAsync = await _service.DataAsync(_todoItem.id, "1000");           

        try
        {
            foreach (var i in PinAsync)
            {


                var todolat = Convert.ToDouble(Lat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var todolon = Convert.ToDouble(Lon, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);



                var todoPin = new Pin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(todolat, todolon),
                    Label = "Hey"
                };
                Map.Pins.Add(todoPin);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No! {0}", err);
        }
    }
```

The passed values are not null. I can set the text in my xaml with it. I just cant send it with my rest call.

Comment: the property is "ID", not "id"

Comment: I don't see where the `TodoItem` property is being set to a non-null value. `_todoItem.ID` cannot be null, because it's of type `int`.

Comment: Where have you initialised `_todoItem`?

Answer (score 0):

First I would rename your item, not using the Class name.

```
public TodoItem MyTodoItem
    {
        get => _todoItem;
        set
        {
            _todoItem = value;
            ID = value.id;
        }
    }
```

And then:

```
 var PinAsync = await _service.DataAsync(MyTodoItem.ID, "1000");
```

Comment: This isn't an answer actually. Why do you think `MyTodoItem` will be not null if `_todoItem` is null?

Comment: Your code isn't complete actually. How can I, or anyone, guess where you set your TodoItem.

Comment: Then you should first ask the OP to clarify the question before providing an answer.